# How to run python script in Nextron.js?

Tags: javascript, python

I have created a project using Nextron.js and have created a button that when pressed will run a python script. I have tried using electron and child_process and I can't get it to work. An unknown error has occurred. Please. Please help me.

```
import React from 'react';

const Home = () => {
  const runPythonScript = () => {
    // ทำสิ่งที่คุณต้องการทำเมื่อผู้ใช้คลิกปุ่มนี้
    const { exec } = require('child_process');
    exec('python path_to_your_script.py', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(`Error executing Python script: ${error}`);
        return;
      }
      console.log(`Python script output: ${stdout}`);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={runPythonScript}>Run Python Script</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```